# Shift element of one sublist to another

Tags: python-3.x, sublist

```
lst=[['a','b'],['c','c'],['e','f'],['g','h']]
```

I need

```
lst=[['a','b'],['c','x'],['c','e'],['f','g'],['h','x']]
```

If both element are same then shift second element to the next sublist and put `'x'` with that element.

Comment: And also add `'x'` as padding to last sublist if needed, I guess?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
lst=[['a','b'],['c','c'],['e','f'],['g','h']]

def my_insert_x(l):
    tmp = []
    for c in l:
        tmp.extend(c)

    res = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:          
            if (tmp[i] == tmp[i + 1]):
                res.append([tmp[i], 'x'])
                i += 1
            else:
                res.append([tmp[i], tmp[i + 1]])
                i += 2
        except:
            if (i == len(tmp) - 1):
                res.append([tmp[i], 'x'])
            break                
    return res

print(my_insert_x(lst))
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'x'], ['c', 'e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h', 'x']]
```